# How to control the space from caption title (Fig. or Table) to caption label (number)?

Tags: captions

I use the package `caption` to set the caption of float. I want to get a large label of captions placing in margin, so I need change the distance of caption title and its label (the default is a `\nobreakspace`).[image]

---EDIT---

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,wrapfig,lipsum,marginnote}

\captionsetup[wrapfigure]{
labelsep=newline,
labelfont={bf},
position=top,
skip=0pt,
singlelinecheck=no}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}[0pt]{4cm}\raggedleft
\marginnote{
\captionof{figure}
{Here is a caption text.}}
\fbox{\parbox{4cm}{aaa\\
bbb\\
ccc\\
ddd\\
eee\\
fff\\
ggg
}}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The code above show:

[image]

But I want is:

[image]

That is say, I want to insert a `\newline` after **Figure** and before **1**.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, I also fixed the width of the \parbox so that the \fbox would fit inside the margin.

My original solution was simple elegant, and wrong.  Specifically, \thefigure is also used in the list of figures.  It took a bit of searching, but I believe \fnum@figure is the right macro to modify.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,wrapfig,lipsum,marginnote}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\figurename\newline\centerline{\huge\thefigure}}
\makeatother

\captionsetup[wrapfigure]{
labelsep=newline,
labelfont={bf},
position=top,
skip=0pt,
singlelinecheck=no}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}[0pt]{4cm}\raggedleft
\marginnote{
\captionof{figure}
{Here is a caption text.}}
\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr 4cm-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{aaa\\
bbb\\
ccc\\
ddd\\
eee\\
fff\\
ggg
}}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: margin caption]

Comment: Thank you. Any why `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\newline\centerline{abc\huge\arabic{figure}}}` don't show the `abc`?

Comment: Did you run it twice?  Works for me.